# How to turn Detached Head into master in git?

Tags: git

In case of Detached Head, how do I remove the commits ahead of Detached Head and turn Detached Head into master?

Comment: You can probably `git checkout -b master` to create a `master` branch at your current commit, which happens to be at a detached HEAD state

Answer (score 4):

It's not quite clear what you mean.

If you want to "Not be in a detached head state anymore, but instead have master checked out, but have master be at the same commit I'm at now with my detached head.", you want to do this:

```
git tag before
git checkout master
git reset --hard before
#git tag -d before
```

Comment: I have this situation happen so often that I'm looking for an way that doesn't involve making a branch all the time. And this is it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `git reset` command to make the current branch point to a commit.

Specifically, get the commit ID that you want to point to, `git checkout master`, then `git reset <ID>`.